# Why is chickenpox more severe in adults?

Tags: infectious-diseases, complications

I've seen in many medical shows and were even told as a kid that chickenpox is quite severe in adults, and that's why it good to catch it and become immune as a child. I've tried researching the reason for the disease being more severe in adults but I've only ever found really vague answers like "chickenpox in adults can lead to complications". What complications? And why are adult more susceptible to these complications? Why don't children suffer from the more severe complications?

Comment: have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chickenpox ? It's a starting point and has links to places where you can read more. Pregnant women can die from chickenpox, for example.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.